# How can I properly import one .proto file into another?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-python

I'm trying to import a message defined in one .proto (`ndarray.proto`) file into another (`image.proto`). My folder structure is:

```
proto/
|
|-- image.proto
|
|-- numproto/
|      |
|      |-- protobuf
|              |
|              |-- ndarray_pb2.py
|              |-- ndarray.proto
```

and inside of `image.proto` I have:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package Image;
import "numproto/protobuf/ndarray.proto";

message image {
    int32 width = 1;
    int32 height = 2;
    numproto.protobuf.NDArray image_data = 3;
}
```

I would expect that I could now assign an NDArray to image_data, but when I try the following in a Python script:

```py
import image_pb2
from numproto import ndarray_to_proto, proto_to_ndarray

image = image_pb2.image()
a = np.hstack((np.ones(10), np.zeros(10)))
data = ndarray_to_proto(a)
image.image_data = data
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "image.proto":
  numproto/protobuf/ndarray.proto: Import "numproto/protobuf/ndarray.proto" has not been loaded.
  Image.image.image_data: "numproto.protobuf.NDArray" seems to be defined in "ndarray.proto", which is not imported by "image.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
```

Am I incorrectly importing the `ndarray.proto` file into `image.proto`?

Comment: Where is the python file located in your folder tree? In the import I do not see the folder protobuf mentioned.

Comment: Try this:
import "proto/numproto/protobuf/ndarray.proto";